# Why is BCrypt specifically effective against rainbow tables?

Tags: encryption, hash, bcrypt, verification

If somebody has the encryption functions from BCrypt, and encrypts a dictionary of passwords and store them on a cd. Gets access to the hashed passwords in the database, shouldn't they be able to?

I hope the answer is no. If so, why not?

Comment: Look up what a salt is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bcrypt, like other PBKDF functions, includes salting and stretching. Salting means that it adds some extra random data with the password. The salt is public. So, for instance, if my salt is "f588d29a" and my password is "password" the thing I'm actually going to hash is "f588d29apassword" (this is not precisely how bcrypt does it, but it is equivalent).

After salting, you'll hash (more in a second), and the output will be: "f588d29a,*hash*". So the salt and hash are known to everyone. But now your rainbow table that includes "password" isn't any use. You need "f588d29apassword" and also "aaaaaaaapassword" and also "aaaaaaabpassword" and also... a *lot* of passwords hashed. So that dramatically increases the amount of time and space you need. And longer salts can make this arbitrarily hard on the attacker for very little cost to the defender. This is the part that makes rainbow tables basically useless. Even if I find multiple people with the same password, their hashes will be different so my table doesn't help.

The second half of bcrypt (and other PBKDFs) is stretching, which means that performing the hash function is time intensive. We're talking tens of milliseconds usually, so it's not a big deal to humans or to one hash, but it makes password guessing much more expensive.

Comment: Another point of view: If every password gets its own salt, a rainbow table will find only this single password, because the rainbow table was built for this specific salt. There is no point in building a whole table just to find one password though, because brute-forcing is faster.

Comment: Stretching is primarily to deter brute force attacks.  If it takes 1/20 second to process a password, then a normal user is not going to notice the slight delay.  However a brute force attacker will only be able to try 20 password guesses a second per processor.  That increases the time and/or cost for an attack.

Comment: Agreed w/ @rossum. I discussed stretching because it's part of bcrypt, but I didn't mean to imply it's related to rainbow tables. Salting alone is enough to defeat rainbow tables (not just deter them; sufficient salting makes the tables useless). Stretching, as rossum notes, is intended to deter brute force attacks.