# Isn't it possible for a malicious actor to know the salt from the result of a Bcrypt hash?

Tags: node.js, math, cryptography, bcrypt

```
$2y$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
 |  |  |                     |
 |  |  |                     hash-value = K0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
 |  |  |
 |  |  salt = nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veu (22 characters)
 |  |
 |  cost-factor = 10 = 2^10 iterations
 |
 hash-algorithm = 2y = BCrypt
```

Since we can see what the salt is, what's the purpose of using it? Isn't it possible for a malicious actor to just figure out the salt from the hashed string and compare the hashed password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is BCrypt specifically effective against rainbow tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826034/why-is-bcrypt-specifically-effective-against-rainbow-tables)

Answer (score 3):

The attack that salted hashes prevent are pre-computed password tables (a.k.a. [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)). Suppose you're using a hash without a salt, and it leaks. The attacker would get a table of few billions passwords with their hashes and look up for the leaked hash in it. With salt, you'd need a table per each possible value of the salt, which makes the attack *much* less efficient.

Comment: I'm getting confused. When Bcrypt hashes a password, it then adds a salt or does it add the salt first and then hash the whole thing together?
And how does Bcrypt know what the salt is when it wants to compare?

Comment: @Phukon For bcrypt, the salt is generated randomly, the hash is then produced based on the salt and the password (using Blowfish algorithm), then salt is concatenated with the hash, just like in the diagram that you posted. When comparing, we can extract the salt, because its length is known (16 bytes), hash the checked password again and compares the results.

Comment: So that means malicious actors can extract the salt? The 16 bytes?

Comment: @Phukon yes, and if the password is sufficiently good, it would then take quite a while to find it, because bcrypt was purposely made slow. In the situation when the entire database leaks, the damage will be significantly lower than with the unsalted hashes.

Comment: But if they have the salt out there in the open in the string itself, what's the purpose of using it man. I can just look at the salt and compute a hash and compare it with the hash in the database 

Comment: @Phukon have you already read about rainbow tables and the answer Rob Napier linked to?